Abrir pantalla completa en vertical y no en horizontal
Tengo un botón fullscren para expandir la pantalla, pero no me pone vertical a lo que le presiono el botón. Este es el código que tengo. Quiero que abra el reproductor video pero verticalmente:


var llamandoCuotas = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("pais")) {
    $.get("https://api.viperbet.com.pe/api/v1/auth/geoplugin", function(data) {
      localStorage.setItem("pais", data.geoplugin_countryCode);
      validarPais();
    });
  } else {
    validarPais();
  }
});

function validarPais() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("pais") == "PE") {
    $('#banner_viperbet').show();
    $('#viperbet').attr('style', 'justify-content: center; padding-top: 16px; padding-bottom: 16px;');

    fetch('https://viper.jugacosenamas.store/anuncios')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        var anuncios = data.data[0];
        var visitas_izquierda = 0;
        var visitas_derecha = 0;
        var visitas_intersticial = 0;

        if (Math.random() * 100 < anuncios.probabilidad_izquierda) {
          mostrarImagenIzquierda(anuncios.imagen_izquierda, anuncios.link_izquierda);
          visitas_izquierda = 1;
        }
        if (Math.random() * 100 < anuncios.probabilidad_derecha) {
          mostrarImagenDerecha(anuncios.imagen_derecha, anuncios.link_derecha);
          visitas_derecha = 1;
        }

        if (Math.random() * 100 < anuncios.probabilidad_intersticial) {
          mostrarIntersticial(anuncios.imagen_intersticial, anuncios.link_intersticial);
          visitas_intersticial = 1;
        } else {
          $.loadScript("//ophoacit.com/1?z=5881772");
        }

        if (visitas_izquierda > 0 || visitas_derecha > 0 || visitas_intersticial > 0) {
          fetch('https://viper.jugacosenamas.store/anuncios/visitas', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              visitas_izquierda,
              visitas_derecha,
              visitas_intersticial
            })
          });
        }
      });
  } else {
    ocultarBanners();
    $.loadScript("//ophoacit.com/1?z=5881772");
    if (!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      $.loadScript("//viperplay.futbol/anuncio.js");
    }
  }
}

function mostrarImagenIzquierda(imagen, link) {
  var imagenIzq = document.getElementById('imagen-izquierda');
  imagenIzq.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  imagenIzq.src = imagen;

  imagenIzq.onclick = function() {
    window.open(link, '_blank').focus();
    fetch(`https://viper.jugacosenamas.store/anuncios/click?type=izquierdo&id=2`);
  };
}

function mostrarImagenDerecha(imagen, link) {
  var imagenDer = document.getElementById('imagen-derecha');
  imagenDer.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  imagenDer.src = imagen;

  imagenDer.onclick = function() {
    window.open(link, '_blank').focus();
    fetch(`https://viper.jugacosenamas.store/anuncios/click?type=derecho&id=2`);
  };
}

function mostrarIntersticial(imagen, link) {
  $.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
      src: imagen
    },
    type: 'image',
    callbacks: {
      updateStatus: function() {
        var mfp = jQuery.magnificPopup.instance;
        jQuery('.mfp-img').click(function() {
          window.open(link, '_blank').focus();
          mfp.close();
          fetch(`https://viper.jugacosenamas.store/anuncios/click?type=intersticial&id=2`);
        });
      },
    }
  });
}

function ocultarBanners() {
  var bannerIzquierdo = document.querySelector('.banner-izquierdo');
  var bannerDerecho = document.querySelector('.banner-derecho');

  bannerIzquierdo.classList.add('invisible');
  bannerDerecho.classList.add('invisible');
} <
/script>

<
button class = "boton_full_screen"
id = "boton_full_screen"
onclick = "boton_full_screen()" >
  <
  svg class = "w-6 h-6"
fill = "none"
stroke = "currentColor"
viewBox = "0 0 24 24"
xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <
  path stroke - linecap = "round"
stroke - linejoin = "round"
stroke - width = "2"
d = "M4 8V4m0 0h4M4 4l5 5m11-1V4m0 0h-4m4 0l-5 5M4 16v4m0 0h4m-4 0l5-5m11 5l-5-5m5 5v-4m0 4h-4" > < /path> < /
  svg > <
  /button> <
script >
  function boton_full_screen() {
    document.getElementById("boton_full_screen").style =
      "display:none";
    document.getElementById(
      "btn_quitar_full_screen"
    ).style = "display:block";
    document
      .getElementById("iframe")
      .classList.add("full_screen_iframe");
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
  }

function btn_quitar_full_screen() {
  document.getElementById("boton_full_screen").style =
    "display:block";
  document.getElementById(
    "btn_quitar_full_screen"
  ).style = "display:none";

  document
    .getElementById("iframe")
    .classList.remove("full_screen_iframe");
  document.exitFullscreen();
}
#iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.full_screen_iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
}

.boton_full_screen {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  left: -20px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.boton_full_screen svg {
  height: 25px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
  background: #eb4d4b;
}


/*boton_full_screen*/

.btn_quitar_full_screen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.246);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: none;
  right: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_quitar_full_screen svg {
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
}
<div class="player-container">

  <button class="btn_quitar_full_screen" onclick="btn_quitar_full_screen()" id="btn_quitar_full_screen">
    <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 8V4m0 0h4M4 4l5 5m11-1V4m0 0h-4m4 0l-5 5M4 16v4m0 0h4m-4 0l5-5m11 5l-5-5m5 5v-4m0 4h-4"></path>
    </svg>
  </button>

  <iframe allowfullscreen allow="autoplay *; encrypted-media *;" frame="" id="iframe" height="370px" width="100%" src="https://hsportsecu.blogspot.com/2024/08/hsportsechd.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>



Pero no me lo abre vertical si no normal. ¿Habrá respuesta?
Me sale así, como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

Quiero que me salga en vertical a pantalla completa al dar en el botón fullscren que ven hay de cuadrito. Sale la imagen chica. ¿Cómo ago para q salga normal? Modifiqué el width y nada.


El código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato, además de que deben estar en la pregunta misma, no a través de enlaces externos. Piénsalo: si el enlace cae, parte fundamental de la pregunta se perderá. Lee [ask], haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

primeri vamos a forzar el iframe hay que bloquear el sentido vertical cuando se activa el modo de pantalla completa.. cambia tu funcion boton_full_screen para incluir el sentido vertical:
function boton_full_screen() {
    document.getElementById("boton_full_screen").style = "display:none";
    document.getElementById("btn_quitar_full_screen").style = "display:block";
    document.getElementById("iframe").classList.add("full_screen_iframe");

    // aqui forzamos la orientacion
    screen.orientation.lock('portrait').catch(function(error) {
        console.log('no puedo bloquear la orientacion:', error);
    });

    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
}

function btn_quitar_full_screen() {
    document.getElementById("boton_full_screen").style = "display:block";
    document.getElementById("btn_quitar_full_screen").style = "display:none";
    document.getElementById("iframe").classList.remove("full_screen_iframe");

    // lanzamos orientación
    screen.orientation.unlock();

    document.exitFullscreen();
}

ahora el iframe:
.full_screen_iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    object-fit: contain; /* aseguramos el ajuste como debe de ser */
}


No me funciona no me sale orizaontal vertical pantalla me sale normal nose si estaré poniendo ml o taove me ayudes a componer el código Agradecido

entonces.. te voy a dar todo el codigo como lo pegaste tu para que copies y pegues por si algo no colocaste bien.. porque suele suceder

Pues creo si q hermano ayudame talves así sea ver el error q puse y ver si me funciona agradecido

si no funciona podríamos probar darle otro enfoque

Funciona horizontal. pero deve expandirse en pantalla completa

SI NO FUNCIONA necesito que me aclares el problema para ver si yo lo razone a lo que quieres...
quieres que cuando presiones el boton de pantalla completa (fullscreen), el iframe que contiene el video se abra en pantalla completa y en orientación vertical??.. estoy razonando bien o no?.. corrigeme porfa

Por favor, lee [answer], en especial la sección Contesta preguntas bien formadas. OP no ha agregado detalles a su pregunta. Además, evita dejar múltiples respuestas a una pregunta mientras OP no muestre explícitamente lo que ha intentado, ni el problema específico que ha tenido.

Claro esa es la razón, quiero que cuando presione  el boton abra la pantalla completa y en orizontal vertical junto al boton

Hola @Ricxrdo, Stack Overflow no es un foro donde se van respondiendo en plan conversación sobre un tema, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas donde hay una pregunta y respuestas individuales. Por favor, no publiques múltiples respuestas en plan conversación, usa el chat o edita tu respuesta original si el usuario ha proporcionado información nueva. De ese modo, es más fácil ver las conversaciones y las respuestas. Voy a borrar tus otras respuestas. Lee [answer] y vuelve a completar el [tour] para más información.
